# jquery resize on mousemove not working

Tags: jquery

I have this js:

```
var clicking = false;

$('.drag-me').mousedown(function(){
    clicking = true;
    $('.status').text('mousedown');
});

$(document).mouseup(function(){
    clicking = false;
    $('.status').text('mouseup');
    $('.status').text('click released, no more move event');
})

$('.drag-me').mousemove(function(e){
    if(clicking == false) return;

    // Mouse click + moving logic here
    $('.status').text('mouse moving');
    var change=lastx-e.pageX;
    var lastx= e.pageX;
    $(this).css('width',$(this).width+change+'px')
    $('.cords').html('x:'+e.pageX+' y: '+e.pageY);
});
```

And html:

```
<div class="drag-me">Drag me</div>
<div class="status">Nothing</div>
<div class="cords">Cords</div>
```

css:

```
.drag-me {
    background:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:30px;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kmEGF/17/)

**QUESTION**:
Now when i move the mouse inside `.drag-me` i want it to increase/decrease its size.
But it doesnt happens so. Why ?
Where have i been going wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

I changed:

```
$(this).css('width',$(this).width+change+'px')
```

to

```
$(this).width(e.pageX);
```

And seemed to get the desired result.

http://jsfiddle.net/kmEGF/26/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/kmEGF/30/ has a few tweaks for two-dimensional resizing and a minimum size.

Comment: I don't think this gives the desired effect, because as soon as you start dragging the width updates to wherever you clicked...

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your code to use .animate() instead of just changing the width, because you can animate with whatever the change in mouse position was...

Here's a live example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kmEGF/31/

and the updated script:

```
var clicking = false;
var lastx;

$('.drag-me').mousedown(function(e){
    clicking = true;
    $('.status').text('mousedown');
    lastx = e.pageX;
});

$(document).mouseup(function(e){
    clicking = false;
    $('.status').text('mouseup');
    $('.status').text('click released, no more move event');
})

$('.drag-me').mousemove(function(e){
    if(clicking == false) return;

    // Mouse click + moving logic here
    $('.status').text('mouse moving');
    var change= -(lastx-e.pageX);
    $(this).stop(true,true).animate({'width': '+='+change})
    $('.cords').html('x:'+e.pageX+' y: '+e.pageY);
    lastx= e.pageX;
});
```

Comment: Ok, let me know if it's not the effect you were looking for.

Comment: Its the same as the given without animation.